# Accessing R history from R code

Tags: r

I am aware of the history function that displays the R history in a separate panel for the user to see.  What I am interested in is slightly different.  I would like to be able to access the R history from R code itself, something where I could ask for the last n commands and get on return a vector containing those commands.  Does anything like that exist?

Answer (score 3):

```
tempfile <- tempfile(pattern="rhistory_", fileext=".txt")
savehistory(tempfile) 
h <- readLines(tempfile)  

tail(h, 5) # display last 5 commands
eval(parse(text=h[length(h)-1])) # exec last command but 1
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping to find a way to do it without going through the file system.